# Why my intent returns null object when pass object between activies?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass connectionHelper object between activies by button. Here is my firs activity

LoginPanelActivity.java

```
       this.forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginPanelActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("connectionHelper", connectionHelper);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Second activity: ForgotPasswordActvity.java

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper;
    SQLQuery sqlQuery;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.forgot_password_layout);
        init();

    }

    private void init()
    {
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper_ = (ConnectionHelper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("connectionHelper");

            if(connectionHelper_ == null)
            {

                this.connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            }

            this.sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(Objects.requireNonNull(this.connectionHelper).getConnection());
    }
```

ConnectionHelper class implemented as Serializable

```
public class ConnectionHelper implements  Serializable {


......

}
```

I want to receive connectionHelper object from activity to another activity to use inside of to avoid connect database in each activity.

Comment: why use activities to begin with, why not use one activity with fragments ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but, make sure each nested class of your main custom class has implemented a Serializable interface to avoid any serialization exceptions.

Also, there is no need to call startActivity like this because you are already in the Activity. Remove v.getContext() before startActivity(intent)

You can also try the Parcelable interface instead of Serializable in case it doesn't work.

Or

you can convert your object into a String using the GSON library and pass it between Activities using Intent but remember to convert it back to an object using GSON when you want to use it.